# Is it possible to use EsLint to format the style in a vue component?

Tags: css, vue.js, eslint, eslintrc

I want to know if anybody know how to format the style in a Vue component using just EsLint (without Prettier). I can't find a rule for this

Comment: Does `eslint --fix` do what you expect?

Comment: ESlint is not a formatter, it's a linter hence it's not it's purpose to format. So, you could **not** have any opinionated formatted looking structure after an ESlint fix. Why is using Prettier a blocker ?

Comment: the --fix does not change the style of a vue component.
In ESlint you can choose the indent, is it not a format rule ? I think ESlint is a formatter and linter

Comment: ESLint is for linting (and to a small degree formatting) ECMAScript. It does not format or lint CSS style rules. You can use `stylelint` for CSS-related languages. In order to make them abide by the same 'basic' settings in terms of indent and such, you can use `editorconfig`. However, IMHO instead of relying on secondary functions of your linter(s) to format, you will get more consistent formatting from turning off any formatting rules in your linter and using Prettier instead, which is specialized for formatting of all types of languages.

Comment: Ok thx, I used `stylelint` with `eslint`

Comment: finally, I used ESLint with `@vue/prettier`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use only `ESLint` to Lint and Format using the `@vue/prettier` config for `ESLint` :

`.eslintrc.js` :

```
    module.exports = { 
       root: true,
       //...
       extends: ['@vue/prettier'],
       //...
       rules: {
          "prettier/prettier": ['error', { semi: false, singleQuote: false }]
       }
    }
```